# The more denim was washed, the softer it would get. (time aspect of 'would')

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, comparative

> The more denim was washed, the softer it would get.

The the sentence describes the past or is it a subjnctive mood which describes 'present situation'?

Comment: It's a habitual occurrence in the past. Each time it was washed, it got softer.

Comment: It is not grammatical. Present tense: The more denim is washed, the softer it gets. Past tense: The more the denim was washed, the softer it would get OR got. Notice: denim and the denim.

Comment: @Lambie You mean no article(denim) is present and yes article(the denim) is past?

Comment: Unless denim as a fabric is changed completely, denim in the past without the is a generality and thus unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Kate Bunting wrote in a comment: "It's a habitual occurrence in the past. Each time it was washed, it got softer."

[From ThoughtCo.](https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829):

> The habitual past is indicated most frequently by the semi-auxiliary verb *used to*, the auxiliary *would*, or the simple past tense of a verb.

[From English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm):

> We sometimes use *would* (rather like *used to*) when talking about habitual past behaviour:
>
> - Every weekday my father would come home from work at 6pm and watch TV.
> - Every summer we'd go to the seaside.
> - Sometimes she'd phone me in the middle of the night.
> - We would always argue. We could never agree.

You can find several discussions of this topic under [this site's "past-habitual" tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-habitual).